# I can i get name of file like this "UTC--2019-07-12T10-13-56.47000000Z--63ab03041e854e1cbefd399eb64786872c5cb3cb.json" in Java?

Tags: java, ethereum, web3js

I'm using web3j for java to create account for my network Ethereum. I need to save in SQL the file name like this.

> "UTC--2019-07-12T10-13-56.47000000Z--63ab03041e854e1cbefd399eb64786872c5cb3cb.json"

But, I don't understand, how I can get this name in web3j.

Answer (score 0):

The last 40 characters: `63ab03041e854e1cbefd399eb64786872c5cb3cb`represent the address of this specific account. 
If I am not mistaken, the date `2019-07-12` corresponds to the creation date.

You can access an address with `web3.eth.getAccount(<Your desired account number>)`.
I suggest you, to try saving the whole name `UTC--2019-07-12T10-13-56.47000000Z--63ab03041e854e1cbefd399eb64786872c5cb3cb.json` in your table with another attribute in the same row containing only the address. This way you can easily query the file name.

Or if you are not able to save another attribute, because you have a fixed table structure, construct yourself some helper method to only extract the last 40 characters of your file name.